# Prevent InternalError: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, callback

I've implemented a function that does things recursively. Because it sometimes needs to do things asynchronously, I can't use a simple `for`/`while` loop and need to use recursive function calls.

In a very abstract snippet this would mean the following:

```
function doStuff(){
   // async or sync things -> depends on several circumstances
   doStuff();
}
doStuff();
```

This works great. But – as you might expect – this causes problems when the maximum recursive call limit is exceeded. Sometimes I need to handle more than 25,000 calls, which causes an `InternalError: too much recursion` in the latest Firefox (50.0a2).

I've found out that catching the InternalError and re-triggering the callback with a timeout works:

```
function doStuff(){
    // async or sync things -> depends on several circumstances
    try{
        doStuff();
    } catch(e if e instanceof InternalError){
        setTimeout(function(){
            doStuff();
        }.bind(this), 25);
    }
}
doStuff();
```

But this looks hacky and ugly. Therefore I'm asking myself what would be the preferred way to workaround this situation – when you can't handle things in a loop and need to use recursive function calls?

Comment: Use a loop as long tail call elimination isn't implemented in current browsers. Note that loops are as expressive as tail recursion and loops with their own stack data structure are as expressive as non-tail recursion. Don't utilize `setTimeout`.

Comment: 1. Why don't utilize `setTimeout`? I know it's ugly, but what functional disadvantage does this have? 2. I can't use a normal loop as I need to run async code at some time. The loop would continue to run...

Comment: `setTimeout` is incredibly slow. However, I don't understand your pseudo code. `doStuff` doesn't take any arguments and returns nothing. The recursive case is blocking. It behaves exactly like a normal loop. And what about the base case?

Comment: In my real application it expects multiple arguments and returns things. What do you mean with base case?

Answer (score 1):

Transform code to asynchronous. It this case your callstack will not be deep

```
function doStuff(){
   setTimeout(doStuff, 0);
}
doStuff();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've found out too (see question). But isn't this a bad practice? Timeouts are always alarm bells for me

Comment: If you must use recursion with so deep callstack, then i see transformation to asyc only. Its not block your UI also (but i think its slower then sync example). why you can't use cycles?

Comment: Alright, thank you. Let's wait a few hours to make sure there's no better approach.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, but makes the application enormously slow. My approach above just makes it slow after each recursion error is thrown.

Comment: you can implement simple counter, about 10000 calls with recursion and then async call. Thats in case you don't like exeptions.